# How to mock default exported modules with jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

## The problem

I'm trying to mock the default exported part of a module, which looks like this:

```
// test.js
const testVariable = {
    blabla: {
        test: 'testContent'
    }
};

export const anotherNotNeedToMockVariable = {};
export default testVariable;
```

The variable I actually need to mock is `test`.

## What I've tried

This implementation gives me an error: `Cannot spy the default property because it is not a function`

```
// toTestModule.js
import test from './test'

export const toTestModuleFunc = async () => {
  console.log('variable mocked', test.blabla.test);
  return test.blabla.test;
};



import * as test from '../test'
import {toTestModuleFunc} from '../toTestModule'

describe('test', () => {
  it('with jest.mock()', async () => {
    const newValue = 'newValue';

    jest.mock('../test', () => ({
        blabla: {
            test: newValue
        }
    }));


    const value = await toTestModuleFunc();
    // this fails
    expect(value).toEqual(newValue);
  });

  it('with jest.spyOn()', async () => {
    const newValue = 'newValue';

    jest.spyOn(test, 'default', 'get').mockImplementation(() => {
      return ({
          blabla: {
              test: newValue
          }
      });
    });


    const value = await toTestModuleFunc();
    // this fails
    expect(value).toEqual(newValue);
  });
});
```

If I change the `jest.spyOn(test, 'default')` to `jest.spyOn(test, 'default', 'get')` it gives me another error: `Property default does not have access type get`

I tried to use `jest.mock()` function, but it does not work with that it never returns the mocked value.

I'd really apreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you want to spy on it? What specifically didn't work with using `jest.mock`.

Comment: Using `jest.mock('./test', () => {mockedvalue})` the variable is actually not mocked, because of hoisting thing, the module is imported before it is mocked

Comment: Can you give a [mre] to clarify what you're testing and what you're trying to mock?

Comment: Just edited the original post, with all the files needed to run and test that it does not work.

Comment: Your `jest.mock` is in the wrong place - if it's not at the top level of the test module, it won't get hoisted above the other imports.

Comment: I dont think you can mock objects. You can wrap testVariable in a function getTestVariable() and mock that one.

Comment: My goal is not to change the file `toTestModule.js`, so wrapping in a function is not an option.